# How to prove this limit: $\lim_{n\to \infty}n(\sqrt[n]{x}-1)=\ln(x)$?

Tags: limits, logarithms, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

I don't know how to prove that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R^+} \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}n(\sqrt[n]{x}-1)=\ln(x)$

with elementary techniques

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769256/trying-to-show-that-lnx-lim-n-to-infty-nx1-n-1/1769257#1769257

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write
$$
n(\sqrt[n]{x}-1)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln x}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
and use the notable limit
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1\quad (\textrm{which implies }\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{at}-1}{t}=a).
$$

Answer (score 2):

> I thought it would be instructive to see a way forward that forgoes use of calculus.  To that end, we proceed.

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequalities

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x}}\tag 1$$

for $x<1$.  Then, using $(1)$ along with the identity $\sqrt[n]{x}=e^{\frac1n \log(x)}$, we have

$$\log(x) \le n\left(e^{\frac1n \log(x)}-1\right)\le \frac{\log(x)}{1-\frac1n \log(x)} \tag 2$$

Applying the squeeze theorem to $(2)$ yields the coveted limit

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}n\left(\sqrt[n]{x}-1\right)=\log(x)}$$

Comment: I cant see why $$\left(e^{\frac1n \log(x)}-1\right)\le \frac{\log(x)}{1-\frac1n \log(x)}$$

Comment: From (1), you get $e^u-1 \leq \frac u{1-u}$. Replace $u $ by $\frac{\log x}{n} $, then multiply both sides by $n $.

Comment: @clementc.  Thanks for the comment.  +1