# Logarithmic formula

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, power-series

By making as few assumptions as possible, prove that

$$\log \left({{1+x} \over {1-x}} \right)=2 \left(\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\cdots\right)$$

for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Can you not use $\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)$?

Comment: Are you intending just to compute the Taylor coefficients directly?

Comment: yep ok, but how do you evaluate log (1+x) from first principles?

Comment: ohk, is it a Taylor expansion then?

Comment: $f(x) = \log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$. Start taking derivatives.

Comment: Well it would be nice to prove any standard formula.

Comment: You have to take *some* formula for granted. For example, the formula for Taylor coefficients. Or are you supposed to derive that from scratch as well? I doubt it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry I meant standard identity.

Comment: Better to use geometric series instead of Taylor.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ok, I understand your point.  Perhaps I needed to clarify that a "standard identity" in this instance is one which could appear in a formula book for an examination.

Comment: I would say "without resorting to formulas trivially related"

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, you're right to say that GP and Taylor are standard formulae, but my question allowed for a solution which contains their proof - and this is easily done for GP.  So I accepted the GP answers.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)$$

And integrate the following:

$$\frac1{1-r}=1+r+r^2+r^3+\dots\forall\ |r|<1$$

Edit:

If you think the geometric series is for granted, see that

$$\frac{1-r^N}{1-r}=1+r+r^2+r^3+\dots+r^{N-1}$$

and take $N\to\infty$

Comment: What you said about the geometric series is true for $|r|\lt1$, however it doesn't work for larger values. Good answer anyway

Comment: @Astyx Note that the domain for the function of interest is $|x|<1$.

Comment: @Astyx if $|x|>1$, use $\frac{1+x}{1-x}=-\left(\frac{1+1/x}{1-1/x}\right)$  also note you will be taking the log of negative numbers at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $|x|<1$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)&=\int_0^{x}\color{#034da3}{\left(\frac{1}{1+u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)}\,du\\\\
&=\int_0^x \color{#034da3}{\frac{2}{1-u^2}}\,du\\\\
&=\int_0^x \overbrace{\color{#034da3}{2\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^{2n}}}^{\color{#034da3}{\text{Geometric Series}}}\,du\\\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}
\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, for $|x|<1$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)&=\int_0^{x}\color{#034da3}{\left(\frac{1}{1+u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)}\,du\\\\
&=\int_0^x \overbrace{\color{#034da3}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1+(-1)^n)u^n}}^{\color{#034da3}{\text{Geometric Series of the integrand}}}\,dx\\\\
&=\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1+(-1)^n)x^{n+1}}{n+1}}_{\text{After integrating the power series term-by-term}}\\\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1 for use of color.  Purple is usually easier on the eyes IMO.  `\color{#ee8844}` is also good.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thank you.  I've heard that optimus blue (RGB=48,77,163) is very easy on the eyes.  But I don't know how to convert the RGB code to the code used here.

Comment: Try `#034da3`.  Simply convert to base 16, where $10=a,11=b,12=c$, etc.  You then get a string of six number/letters, and just put them in RGB order.  And I agree it looks nice.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thanks for the edit.  I don't know much about color codes and wasn't even aware that it was a matter of converting bases.  So, how does one go from RGB(a,b,c) to the same color here?

Comment: $48=\underline3\times16+\underline0\implies46\to30.\ 77=\underline4\times16+\underline{13}\implies77\to4(13)=4d.\ 163=\underline{10}\times16+\underline3\implies(10)3=a3$, where $a=10,\ b=11,\dots,\ f=16$

Answer (score 0):

Use Taylor expansion for $\ln(1+x)$, it is $\ln(1+x)=x-1/2x^2+1/3x^3-1/4x^4+... $, so similarly you can know $\ln(1-x)=-x+1/2x-1/3x^3-1/4x^4+...$.

Now let look at $\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})=\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=2/(x+1/3x^3+1/5x^5+...)$

Answer (score 0):

From the non-standard definition of the logarithm [proved here] ([Trying to show that $\ln(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n(x^{1/n} -1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769256/trying-to-show-that-lnx-lim-n-to-infty-nx1-n-1))

$$\log(t):=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(t^{1/n}-1)$$

after substituting $t=1+x$, we get

$$\log(1+x):=\lim_{n\to\infty}n((1+x)^{1/n}-1).$$

Then using the generalized binomial theorem and the falling factorial notation,

$$\log(1+x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac1n\right)_{k}\frac{x^k}{k!}-1\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n\right)_{k}\frac{x^k}{k!}.$$

As the coefficient of the $k^{th}$ power is

$$n\left(\frac1n\right)_k=n\frac1n\left(\frac1n-1\right)\cdots\left(\frac1n-k+1\right)=\left(\frac1n-1\right)\cdots\left(\frac1n-k+1\right),$$

its limit is clearly $(-1)(-2)\cdots(-k+1)=(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!$

Then

$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k}$$ and

$$\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}.$$

---

For complete rigor, one needs to justify that the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits.

Comment: Note that this "non-standard" definition is indeed the original, classical definition of the logarithm as it derived from the power tables of Napier et al. The exponential function was thus originally defined as the inverse of the natural logarithm.

Comment: Actually, I've found out that this "non-standard definition" is certainly not the original one first derived by Napier and his 16th century colleagues.  In fact the original Naperian log is defined very differently (according to  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napierian_logarithm).