# Non-trivial definition of logarithmic function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms

Prove that
$$\log(t):=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(t^{1/n}-1),$$ for any $t>0$.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769256/trying-to-show-that-lnx-lim-n-to-infty-nx1-n-1/1769257#1769257

Comment: Also, $\log t$ is only defined for $t>0$.

Comment: I originally marked it as a duplicate immediately after submitting it.  It should show my name for that.